# Position image above map

Tags: swift

this question applies to any item but in this case I would like to position my image above the map, currently it gets place below the map.

I am new to swift 1.2 so I do not know how to put together an example, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about above in X-Y terms or in Z terms? If Z terms, and using interface builder, you can go to editor->Arrange->Bring forward, or just move the image in the relation to the other UI elements, as their order in the below menu defines their Z-order.

[image]